# Showing specific video thumbnail basing on user's language

Tags: video, multilingual, thumbnails, vimeo

Videos hosted in Vimeo have subtitles in several languages for multilingual watchers. However, Vimeo supports only one active thumbnail and video title text burned in thumbnail image is shown on that language.

Is there way to upload several thumbnails (each with video title text on different language) and request specific thumbnail in iframe call? If not Vimeo, does any other service supports this?

Alternatively if video title is removed on thumbnail, is it possible to add multilingual video title in metadata and request specific to shown in top of thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

How are you ?

Vimeo doesn't give the option to have multiple thumbnails, every thumbnail uploaded need to be set to Active based on the steps set before as you can see here.

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/thumbnails

Comment: Thank you! Do you know can any other video hosting service support multiple thumbnails?

Comment: Actually not :)